# ArcMap Tool Error Message

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I am currently working on mapping my local fire departments incident responses over the last three years. I have the data in an Excel workbook and would like to bring it in to ArcMap 10.2.2 to analyze and export data as a shapefile. I can get the table loaded to a blank map but when I try to display XY data (right-clicking in the TOC) the system freezes or crashes. When I search the tool box for the make XY event tool it finds it, but when I click on it I receive a script error message:

> An error has occurred in this script on this page. Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

What would be causing this error? I am not great with computers but I was wondering if it is because my Excel workbook contains to many features (almost 300,000). Or, is it because my computer is not strong enough to run this data and tools. I have an AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Core Processor 5000+  2.60GHz  3GB RAM  32-bit OS  and running Windows Vista SP2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300K rows should not be a problem to read into ArcGIS however your PC configuration is somewhat limited and according to the error message you get, you are running out of memory.

Just to verify that your data is prepared properly, try creating an .xls file (note, not .xlsx) with just a few incidents and see if it works (keep in mind that .xls can only have 65,536 rows). If things work fine, try splitting your Excel into smaller portions (start with 100K rows Excel file) and try creating XY event layer from that. If you get the same error, split the file in half and continue.

If it doesn't, then it means there might be something wrong with the Excel sheet.

In this case:

1. Read about preparing Excel sheet [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/esritrainingmatters/2008/11/25/formatting-excel-data-for-use-in-arcgis-desktop/), [here](http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30727), and [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000001w000000). There are certain rules about the columns names, data formats, etc.
2. Try converting your Excel into a file geodatabase table by running the [Excel to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001200000055000000) GP tool. Explore the output table to make sure your coordinates and other relevant information was read successfully.
3. Try creating a feature class from the table (read [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001z000000) on how to do that).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My system could not handle the file size and breaking it down worked. I revisited the data to clean the number of attributes, to shed the fat and also got it to work. Thank you for the assistance.